# How to store file on Bucket s3 with specific tree and then Zip it

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, smartsheet-api

I'm working on this but amazon aws s3 is not my favorite part so I need some help with this:

```py
import smartsheet
import time
import os
import json
import shutil
import zipfile
import boto3

#Initialisation Variables et Environment

token = api_token
ss = smartsheet.Smartsheet(token)
ssh = ss.Home.list_all_contents()
backupdir = "d:\\Backup"
if not os.path.exists(backupdir):
    os.mkdir(backupdir)
zipname = "SmartsheetBackup - " + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
odir = "d:\\Backup\\SmartsheetBackup - " + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
lsthome = json.loads(ssh.to_json())
sss = ss.Sheets.list_sheets(include_all=True) 
lstsheetsall = json.loads(sss.to_json())
rapport = open(odir + " Report.txt", "w+")
rapportname = zipname + " Report.txt"
lstsheets = []
workspaces = ss.Workspaces.list_workspaces(include_all=True)
lstworkspaces = json.loads(workspaces.to_json())
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketname)

#Fin Initialisation
```

so actually with this setup we got:

- api_token which is the token smartsheet to backup data
- backupdir that would change with the bucket
- zipname the final name of the zip created
- ss,ssh,lsthom,lstsheetsall,lstsheets,workspaces,lstworkspaces are specific to my smartsheet-api var
- and the bucket s3 var with the bucket name

```py
#Création Dossier de backup, rapport de backup

os.mkdir(odir)
rapport.write("---------- Starting Backup ----------\n\n")
rapport.write(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M\n\n'))
```

here I'm creating a report file where I will put the timestamps etc...

```py
#Backup des dossiers et sheets Inférieurs ou égales à F+2

print("Tool About to backup folder and sheets equals and less than f+2")
rapport.write("Start Backup Folders <= F+2\n\n")
for folder in lsthome['folders']:
    rapport.write("Create Folder : " + folder['name'] + "\n")
    os.mkdir(odir + "\\" + folder['name'])
    os.chdir(odir + "\\" + folder['name'])
    cdir = os.getcwd()
    for sheets in folder['sheets']:
        rapport.write("Download : " + sheets['name'] + "\n")
        ss.Sheets.get_sheet_as_excel(sheets['id'], os.getcwd())
        lstsheets.append(sheets['id'])
    if folder['folders'] == '[]':
        break
    else:
        for sfolder in folder['folders']:
            rapport.write("Create Folder : " + sfolder['name'] + "\n")
            os.mkdir(sfolder['name'])
            os.chdir(sfolder['name'])
            for ssheets in sfolder['sheets']:
                rapport.write("Download : " + ssheets['name'] + "\n")
                ss.Sheets.get_sheet_as_excel(ssheets['id'], os.getcwd())
                lstsheets.append(ssheets['id'])
rapport.write("Folder and sheets f+2 Backup OK \n\n")
print("Folders And Sheets Backup OK !")

#Fin De Backup des Dossiers
```

Then I Backup folder and file folder + 2 max with the right tree. (With s3 it should be faster)

```py
#Initialisation du Backup des fichiers root

print("Tool About to backup Root Sheets")
rapport.write("Download Root Sheets \n")
for bsheets in lsthome['sheets']:
    os.chdir(odir)
    ss.Sheets.get_sheet_as_excel(bsheets['id'], os.getcwd())
    rapport.write("Download Rsheets : " + bsheets['name'] + "\n")
    lstsheets.append(bsheets['id'])
rapport.write("Root Sheets Backup OK \n\n")
print("Root Sheets Bakcup OK !")

#Fin de backup des fichier root
```

There is the backup of root file

```py
#Backup des sheets restants dans SheetsSup

os.chdir(odir)
print("Tool About to backup file in more than f+2")
os.mkdir(odir + "\\SheetsSup")
os.chdir(odir + "\\SheetsSup")
rapport.write("\n\nBackup sheets over f+2\n\n")
if not(str(lstsheetsall['totalCount']) == str(len(lstsheets))):
    for sheetsall in lstsheetsall['data']:
        if not(sheetsall['id'] in lstsheets):
            rapport.write("Download : " + sheetsall['name'] + "\n")
            ss.Sheets.get_sheet_as_excel(sheetsall['id'], os.getcwd())
    os.chdir(odir)
rapport.write("Sheets Backup OK \n")
print("Sheets Backup Sup OK !")

#Fin backup Sheets over F+2
```

Here are the rest of the files (over folder + 2)

```py
#Initialisation Backup Attachments

rapport.write("\n\nStart Backup Attachments\n\n")
print("Tool About to backup Attachments")
os.mkdir(odir + "\\Attachments")
os.chdir(odir + "\\Attachments")
for sheetsall in lstsheetsall['data']:
    DLA = ss.Attachments.list_all_attachments(sheetsall['id'], include_all=True)
    action = DLA.data
    for col in action:
        rapport.write("Download : " + col.name + "\n")
        attachurl = ss.Attachments.get_attachment(sheetsall['id'],col.id)
        ss.Attachments.download_attachment(attachurl, os.getcwd())
print("Download Attachments OK !")
rapport.write("Download Attach OK")

#Fin de backup attachments
```

Attachments on file and in folder smartsheet

```py
#Initialisation Zip Dossier Backup + Fichier rapport

os.chdir(backupdir)
print("Zipping Backup")
rapport.write("Zipping Archive")
shutil.make_archive(zipname, 'zip', odir)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname + ".zip", 'a')
rapport.write("\n\nRapport end at : " + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') + "\n")
rapport.write("----------- Ending Backup -----------")
rapport.close()
z.write(rapportname)
z.close()
print("Zipping Complete !")

#Fin de Zipping Dossier

#Néttoyage fichier et dossier

shutil.rmtree(odir)
os.remove(rapportname)

#Fin de Programme
```

Zipping of the folder root then del al files to just keep the zip.

**Problem**

And Now The Problem is how to make the same program but replacing my local storage that is my d:\folder to an s3 storage.

This Python program should be run with a lambda that schedule it to time to time (example : every day or 2 days). So No transition between PC in local.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to download to local storage, and then upload to S3.

Boto (https://github.com/boto/boto3) is the Python library for S3.

Comment: But the Running of the python program will be stored on a lambda for the schedule task and the data will only travel between smartsheet to s3